# gpg2 - Unusable public key -No assurance key belongs to named user

Tags: password-management, gnupg

I'm using pass as my main password manager(which uses gpg2), but since a few days i can't create new keys, I always get the error message:

```
There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user
[stdin]: encryption failed: Unusable public key
```

I already set the the trust of my key to ultimate als suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361068/gnupg-there-is-no-assurance-this-key-belongs-to-the-named-user#34132924)

And also checked that my key is not expired.
Any suggestions how to fix this or should i get a new key?

Comment: I voted to migrate your question to [su]. I think it might be a better fit there.

Comment: This is better asked on the pass mailing list.

Answer (score 8):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361068/gnupg-there-is-no-assurance-this-key-belongs-to-the-named-user:

do `gpg --edit-key <KEY_ID>`
and `gpg>trust`

If you're sure about the authenticity of your key, select the trust level 5.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question i already tried this and it didn't resolve my issue. I solved it running pass init again on the directory with my gpg-key

Answer (score 3):

I had simillar issue. In my case I generated the GPG key for `RSA (sign only)`.

It can be fixed either by regenerating it for **`RSA and RSA (default)`** of by adding a subkey for `RSA (encrypt only)`.

The second option can be done by `gpg --edit-key <KEY_ID>` and `gpg> addkey` and select `RSA (encrypt only)`

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem by running:`pass init <gpg-id>` which reencrypted the existing keys.
Afterwards i was able to decrypt my keys again normaly