# How do I tell pass to update my key if `pass init` isn't working?

Tags: gnupg, password-management, pgp, public-key-encryption

I am trying to use `pass` again after a longish lull, and it was (reasonably) complaining that my gpg key was expired. I used the instructions at [Can you extend the expiration date of an already expired GPG key?](https://superuser.com/questions/813421/can-you-extend-the-expiration-date-of-an-already-expired-gpg-key) to extend the expiration date. When I do `gpg --list-keys` it now shows as expiring in 2028.

Per [gpg2 - Unusable public key -No assurance key belongs to named user](https://superuser.com/questions/1297502/gpg2-unusable-public-key-no-assurance-key-belongs-to-named-user) I also ran `pass init amanda@rajje` which is indeed the name of my key. That went fine: `Password store initialized for amanda@rajje`.

But when I try to add a new key to `pass` it says it cannot retrieve my key:

```
gpg: error retrieving 'amanda@rajje' via Local: Unusable public key
gpg: error retrieving 'amanda@rajje' via WKD: Connection refused
gpg: amanda@rajje: skipped: Connection refused
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: Connection refused
```

And when I retrieve other passwords from `pass` it says
gpg: Note: secret key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX expired at Fri 05 Jul 2019 01:41:06 PM PDT
zq

Some how `pass` is still convinced that my key is expired.

Comment: I wound up generating a new key and initializing `pass` with it, but I'd still like to know how to convince `pass` that my updated expiry is real.